# Gradle: What is the benefit if I switch from Groovy to Kotlin?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm a Android developer. As result I use Gradle for build android projects. I write (about 2 years) gradle scripts on Groovy. As result scripts is very compact, clear and easy to support. It is very good.

But in new version of Gradle is introduce new language - Kotlin.

My question is: What is the benefit (for writing Gradle scripts) if I switch from Groovy to Kotlin?

Comment: https://blog.gradle.org/kotlin-meets-gradle.

Comment: beware that kotlin buildscript can be slow, both to build and to edit in IDE https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-24668 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-14829

Answer (score 49):

Kotlin is **statically** typed, whereas Groovy is not. Statically typed languages like Kotlin enable IDEs to support particular tasks much better:

- auto-completion and content assist
- quick documentation
- navigation to source
- refactoring and more

This is a great advantage that Gradle sees and therefore started with Kotlin as an alternative to Groovy.

There are also some official statements which you can find [here](https://blog.gradle.org/kotlin-meets-gradle).

Kotlin has become a standard scripting language in the Gradle ecosystem as you can see in their [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html).

Comment: By Groovy I can generate (create dynamic) Gradle tasks (on fly).It's very powerfull mechanism. And it's ofnen help me. My question is: Is it possible on Kotlin?

Comment: Yes, you can https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:dynamic_tasks

Answer (score 3):

I found this blog which explains some advantages to use Gradle Kotlin compare to Gradle Groovy: https://gradlehero.com/5-reasons-to-switch-to-the-gradle-kotlin-dsl/.

Quick resume of these advantages:

- Simplified plugins syntax
- Default lazy task configuration
- Compile time checks
- Better IDE experience
- Advantages of Kotlin language compare to Groovy Language

Hope it's could help.